# What is the difference between make and make dist?

Tags: makefile

What's the difference between `make` and `make dist`? I understand that dist is a "target", but what target is used by default, and what does the dist target typically do differently from the default make?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-dist-_0028standard-target_0029

Comment: That sounds like it just makes a source bundle but make dist on the Xen repo complies everything

Comment: Xen for whatever reason chose to make [`dist` an alias of `all`](http://xenbits.xen.org/gitweb/?p=xen.git;a=blob_plain;f=Makefile;hb=refs/heads/master), there's no difference in this case, but generally `dist` creates a source distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"dist" is used to create a distribution tar file for this program.
Please refer https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html for more details.